# Linking my Wordpress log to Google Buzz

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, blogs, google-buzz

Is there a way for Wordpress to automatcally post to my Google Buzz account, I saw one way but it looked like WAY too much effort having add a rel=me link and forcing Google to recrawl your site. Surely there's an easier way than this. The temptation is just to use the social buttons on my site after I post but I'd much prefer to do this automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to add a link to your Google profile. It's not a big deal from your wordpress link manager.

After Google recrawls your site, you'll get the option to add it in your Google Buzz stream